# Como faço um comando com substring?

Tags: lua

Como faço uma substring com um comando (ultilizando io.read)? exemplo:

io.read() pergunta
Eu respondo: say Hello World
depois o console "printa" "Hello World".

"say" é o comando "Hello World" é a substring.

Answer (score 1):

Use string.match como no exemplo abaixo:

```
s=io.read()
c,m=s:match("(%S+)%s+(.+)$")
if c=="say" then
    print(m)
end
```

O padrão usado em match é: procura e captura uma sequência de caracteres não espaços, pula espaços, captura o resto da linha.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta. Só mais uma coisa, pode comentar a 2ª primeiras linhas para eu saber o que cada coisa faz?